# Text containing Hyperlinks, order of elements in xpath

Tags: xpath, hyperlink, scrapy

I am using scrapy with lxml-3.2.4 to crawl few newspaper articles. These articles sometimes contain HyperLinks and are in different nodes in the webpage from the rest of the text.
This is the link of such an article:
http://www.business-standard.com/article/companies/wipro-on-a-major-recruitment-drive-113122300827_1.html

I want to extract the article contents and for this I have written this code:

```
hxs = Selector(response)
detailsPath = hxs.xpath('//*[@class="articleContentBox"]')
textall =  detailsPath.xpath('//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*')
for text in textall:
    contents = text.xpath('text()').extract()
    for content in contents:
          data.append(unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',content).encode('ascii','ignore'))
finaltext = "\n".join(data)
```

I want the article contents to come like this:

```
Bangalore-based information technology (IT) services firm Wipro is on a major recruitment drive. The company would evaluate 50,000-60,000 students from 350 colleges in FY15.
Last year, Wipro had offered letters to 3,000-4,000 students with science background, and the company plans to hire more in FY15, said Rajiv Kumar, global campus head, Wipro. Kumar did not reveal the exact number of recruitments.
“Campus hiring has always been strategic to Wipro’s hiring strategy. But other than hiring engineers, we have been hiring students from science background in good numbers through two of our programmes -- Wipro Academy of Software Engineers and Wipro Software Technology Academy,” added Kumar.
According to sources, about 5,000 students were inducted and another 11,000 are in the process of joining the company through these programmes. The programmes had been launched in partnership with BITS Pilani and Vellore Institute of Technology. During the traning, the company takes care of the fee, books and accomodation. Besides, students are given a stipend of about Rs 12,000 in the first year and goes up to 20,000 in the fourth year.
“These are true earn-as-you-learn programmes. After four years, their career paths are similar to any engineer. They can start as developer, project manager etc. More importantly, we do not sign any bond with the student. So after the fourth year, if a candidate wishes to leave Wipro, they can. The only condition is that they have to complete the four-year tenure,” said Kumar.
Kumar said candidates who have completed the programmes would draw more salary than that of an engineer. “They get paid more than an entry level engineering candidate. It is generally in the range of Rs 4,00,000–6,00,000 per annum,” he said. The average salary an entry level engineer draws is around Rs 3,00,000–Rs  3,50,000 per annum.
“Our experience tells us that the attrition rate in this group is in single digits: Much lower than the company average. Also, we do not hire these students for our BPO operations,” said Kumar.
```

But instead The articles contents are coming like this(The text in hyperlinks is coming at the end)

```
Bangalore-based information technology (IT) services firm 
 is on a major recruitment drive. The company would evaluate 50,000-60,000 students from 350 colleges in FY15.
Last year, Wipro had offered letters to 3,000-4,000 students with science background, and the company plans to hire more in FY15, said Rajiv Kumar, global campus head, Wipro. Kumar did not reveal the exact number of recruitments.
Campus hiring has always been strategic to Wipros hiring strategy. But other than hiring engineers, we have been hiring students from science background in good numbers through two of our programmes -- Wipro Academy of Software Engineers and Wipro Software Technology Academy, added Kumar.
According to sources, about 5,000 students were inducted and another 11,000 are in the process of joining the company through these programmes. The programmes had been launched in partnership with 
 and 
. During the traning, the company takes care of the fee, books and accomodation. Besides, students are given a stipend of about Rs 12,000 in the first year and goes up to 20,000 in the fourth year.
These are true earn-as-you-learn programmes. After four years, their career paths are similar to any engineer. They can start as developer, project manager etc. More importantly, we do not sign any bond with the student. So after the fourth year, if a candidate wishes to leave Wipro, they can. The only condition is that they have to complete the four-year tenure, said Kumar.
Kumar said candidates who have completed the programmes would draw more salary than that of an engineer. They get paid more than an entry level engineering candidate. It is generally in the range of Rs 4,00,0006,00,000 per annum, he said. The average salary an entry level engineer draws is around Rs 3,00,000Rs  3,50,000 per annum.
Our experience tells us that the attrition rate in this group is in single digits: Much lower than the company average. Also, we do not hire these students for our BPO operations, said Kumar.
Wipro
BITS Pilani
Vellore Institute of Technology
```

Please tell me a way to extract the elements in the order they appear(preferably in python) and thus remove this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the output of XPath `//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*`, you'll notice that `descendant-or-self::*` selects

- `<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">` (because of the `-or-self`)
- `<p itemprop="articleBody">` (descendant of the `div` above)
- the 3 `<a class="storyTags" href="...`, descendants of the `p` (and the `div`)
- all the `br` elements

Using `scrapy shell http://www.business-standard.com/article/companies/wipro-on-a-major-recruitment-drive-113122300827_1.html`:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(sel.xpath('//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*'))
[<Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.o'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<p itemprop="articleBody">\r\n         \r\n '>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<a class="storyTags" href="/search?type='>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<a class="storyTags" href="/search?type='>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<a class="storyTags" href="/search?type='>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>,
 <Selector xpath='//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/descendant-or-self::*' data=u'<br>'>]
>>>
```

Then, applying `.xpath('text()')` will extract child text nodes from these elements.

The `div` has only whitespaace text:

```
>>> sel.xpath('//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/self::*/text()').extract()
[u'\r\n         ', u'\r\n       ']
>>>
```

The `p` has most of the content you want, but notice the text inside links is not there (text in links are child text nodes of `a`, not text children of `p`):

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(sel.xpath('//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/p/text()').extract())
[u'\r\n         \r\n    \r\nBangalore-based information technology (IT) services firm ',
 u' is on a major recruitment drive. The company would evaluate 50,000-60,000 students from 350 colleges in FY15.',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\nLast year, Wipro had offered letters to 3,000-4,000 students with science background, and the company plans to hire more in FY15, said Rajiv Kumar, global campus head, Wipro. Kumar did not reveal the exact number of recruitments.',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n\u201cCampus hiring has always been strategic to Wipro\u2019s hiring strategy. But other than hiring engineers, we have been hiring students from science background in good numbers through two of our programmes -- Wipro Academy of Software Engineers and Wipro Software Technology Academy,\u201d added Kumar.',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\nAccording to sources, about 5,000 students were inducted and another 11,000 are in the process of joining the company through these programmes. The programmes had been launched in partnership with ',
 u' and ',
 u'. During the traning, the company takes care of the fee, books and accomodation. Besides, students are given a stipend of about Rs 12,000 in the first year and goes up to 20,000 in the fourth year.',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n\u201cThese are true earn-as-you-learn programmes. After four years, their career paths are similar to any engineer. They can start as developer, project manager etc. More importantly, we do not sign any bond with the student. So after the fourth year, if a candidate wishes to leave Wipro, they can. The only condition is that they have to complete the four-year tenure,\u201d said Kumar.',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\nKumar said candidates who have completed the programmes would draw more salary than that of an engineer. \u201cThey get paid more than an entry level engineering candidate. It is generally in the range of Rs 4,00,000\u20136,00,000 per annum,\u201d he said. The average salary an entry level engineer draws is around Rs 3,00,000\u2013Rs\xa0 3,50,000 per annum.',
 u'\r\n',
 u'\r\n\u201cOur experience tells us that the attrition rate in this group is in single digits: Much lower than the company average. Also, we do not hire these students for our BPO operations,\u201d said Kumar.']
>>>
```

And finally, the text nodes of `a` elements:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(sel.xpath('//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div//a/text()').extract())
[u'Wipro', u'BITS Pilani', u'Vellore Institute of Technology']
>>>
```

`br` elements have no child text nodes

```
>>> sel.xpath('//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div//br/text()').extract()
[]
>>>
```

One solution is to extract the text representation of the `<p itemprop="articleBody">` using `string()`

```
>>> print(sel.xpath('string(//*[@class="colL_MktColumn2"]/div/div/p)').extract()[0])



Bangalore-based information technology (IT) services firm Wipro is on a major recruitment drive. The company would evaluate 50,000-60,000 students from 350 colleges in FY15.

Last year, Wipro had offered letters to 3,000-4,000 students with science background, and the company plans to hire more in FY15, said Rajiv Kumar, global campus head, Wipro. Kumar did not reveal the exact number of recruitments.

“Campus hiring has always been strategic to Wipro’s hiring strategy. But other than hiring engineers, we have been hiring students from science background in good numbers through two of our programmes -- Wipro Academy of Software Engineers and Wipro Software Technology Academy,” added Kumar.

According to sources, about 5,000 students were inducted and another 11,000 are in the process of joining the company through these programmes. The programmes had been launched in partnership with BITS Pilani and Vellore Institute of Technology. During the traning, the company takes care of the fee, books and accomodation. Besides, students are given a stipend of about Rs 12,000 in the first year and goes up to 20,000 in the fourth year.

“These are true earn-as-you-learn programmes. After four years, their career paths are similar to any engineer. They can start as developer, project manager etc. More importantly, we do not sign any bond with the student. So after the fourth year, if a candidate wishes to leave Wipro, they can. The only condition is that they have to complete the four-year tenure,” said Kumar.

Kumar said candidates who have completed the programmes would draw more salary than that of an engineer. “They get paid more than an entry level engineering candidate. It is generally in the range of Rs 4,00,000–6,00,000 per annum,” he said. The average salary an entry level engineer draws is around Rs 3,00,000–Rs  3,50,000 per annum.

“Our experience tells us that the attrition rate in this group is in single digits: Much lower than the company average. Also, we do not hire these students for our BPO operations,” said Kumar.
>>>
```